# Is there a word for a question whose phrasing renders its answer essentially useless?

Tags: meaning, terminology, questions

I am looking for a word similar to "uninformative" but not quite, since "uninformative" applies to the *answer* but I want the word for the corresponding question with an answer that is necessarily uninformative. Arguably, rhetorical questions are a subset of this sort of question, but there are other types as well so that's not quite satisfactory. I've thought of "useless" and its synonyms but was wondering if there is a term specifically for questions of this sort.

The context, for me, is that people frequently ask "is this possible?" in terms of work projects, the answer to which is always "yes", but they really needed to ask "is this practical" or "how long will this take?"

Comment: Please supply a few examples of such questions. Thanks.

Comment: Added example. Also, as originally noted, every rhetorical question is an example of this.

Comment: This seems to be a value judgement on questions which may be open-ended, or leading. In the example it should be clear what is being asked, and an informative reply could be "Yes, I believe it can be done in two months, provided we can find the right material."

Comment: OK, so it is a value judgment. But is there a word that describes these sorts of questions in the context of this value judgment? I don't understand how that changes anything. Also, these questions are typically the exact opposite of "open-ended", their nature is that the answer can be self-evident or implied in the question itself.

Comment: The example of *Is this possible?* doesn't necessarily result in an "essentially useless" answer. In the first place, I disagree that "yes" is without meaning. But, that aside, the person who answers isn't forced to answer with a simple "yes" in the first place. They could easily answer *Yes, if we do this, this, and this, but not if we do that.*

Comment: I don't agree that all rhetorical questions are in this category. Sometimes a rhetorical question does have a useful answer, but the audience is assumed to understand what that answer is without it being explicitly stated.

Comment: The way your example is phrased, this is a hedged (polite) request (or rather, if this is the boss, requirement) that you (or your underlings) _do_ the task. An easy-to-see example is 'Can you open the window, please, John.' Modern punctuation allows the full stop rather than a question mark: this is a polite request that John open the window, not an enquiry about his physical capabilities.

Comment: I've heard such false inquiries called counterfeit questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would classify some of the questions where the answer is known but the question is not apparently rhetorical as 'manipulative'.

Your example, 'Is this possible?', may be asked in 2 contexts:

1. feasibility in general, based on practices
2. the respondent's preliminary readiness, ability, confirmation, and agreement to undertake a task.

In the first case, an alternative wording may be 'Is this feasible?', while the second case can be replaced with 'Can you do it?'.

If the asker knows it is feasible and the respondent is capable of the implementation, then the question is a manipulative way to make the respondent share the responsibility.